# Moment.js How to correctly parse string into a date object and calculate time difference?

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, momentjs

Some context:

In my react-native app I'm trying to check two dates to see if there is a day difference. If there is a day difference, perform a function.

The problem is, I have to store today's date (done with `var today = moment()` ) as a string into AsyncStorage, and then retrieve that string next time the app is launched and turn it back into a moment object.

First object is called `today` and the other is `lastChecked`. When I run `var dayDiff = today.diff(lastChecked, 'days')` it returns 0.

I ran `console.log` on both objects and here is what it shows. 
`_d` is the same on both objects, however the second object has a `_i` object that contains my desired date taken from the AsyncStorage.

How would I correctly set the lastChecked object to contain that date and compare day difference using that date?

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Thu Oct 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time), …}
_d: Thu Oct 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time) {}
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, …}
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__: Object
index.js:176 

Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2019-10-02T16:00:00.000Z", _f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ", _tzm: 0, _isUTC: true, …}
_d: Thu Oct 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Australian Western Standard Time) {}
_f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ"
_i: "2019-10-02T16:00:00.000Z"
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, …}
_offset: 0
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -1, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
_tzm: 0
__proto__: Object
```

edit: Fixed code formatting

Comment: Thu Oct 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 and 2019-10-02T16:00:00.000Z are the same moment in time, the difference is 0 days.

Comment: Actually they should be one day apart as one is 3rd October and the other is 2nd.
The problem is that the time is 16:00. The day difference is less than 1, and I was calculating the time difference without the float type parameter applied. When passing true to the time difference function, it returns 0.66

Comment: You are mistaken, they are the same moment in time. The first timestamp is 8 hours ahead of UTC. Subtract 8 hours and you'll get Wed Oct 02 2019 16:00:00, which is the date and time of the second (UTC) timestamp.

Comment: Yes you're right! My mistake. 
The solution I left below helped me resolve the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue.

The problem was that the LastChecked parameter was never set to `.startOf('day')` and took in the actual time (in this case being 16:00).

Calculating the time difference in days would return 0 as the default function returns only integers. Passing a bool like this: `var dayDiff = today.diff(LastChecked, 'days', true)` would return a float value.

In my case it returned 0.66

Additionally, if you want to see what date it actually compares then call `console.log(today.toString())`

The other problem I found was that because I initialised the LastChecked moment object as `let LastCheck = moment()` it took on current time. So when initialising, set it to: `let LastCheck = moment().startOf('day')`